# Google PubSub - Counting messages in topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I've looked over the documentation for Google's PubSub, and also tried looking in Google Cloud Monitoring, but couldn't find any means of figuring out what's the queue size in my topics.

Since I plan on using PubSub for analytics, it's important for me to monitor the queue count, so I could scale up/down the subscriber count.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The metric you want to look at is "undelivered messages." You should be able to set up alerts or charts that monitor this metric in [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://app.google.stackdriver.com) under the "Pub/Sub Subscription" resource type. The number of messages that have not yet been acknowledged by subscribers, i.e., queue size, is a per-subscription metric as opposed to a per-topic metric. For info on the metric, see `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages` in the [GCP Metrics List](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) (and others for all of the Pub/Sub metrics available).

Comment: Because I had only signed up for the monitoring service yesterday, I was not yet able to see Pub/Sub under the "Resources" tab - now it's there.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried to query an API directly and got NotFound error. https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/<name_of_subscription>/num_undelivered_messages This is a url. What am i missing?

Answer (score 14):

This might help if you're looking into a programmatic way to achieve this:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import query

project = "my-project"
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
result = query.Query(
         client,
         project,
         'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages', 
         minutes=60).as_dataframe()

print(result['pubsub_subscription'][project]['subscription_name'][0])
```

Comment: Awesome, this saved me tons of time.  Thanks!

Comment: @Steeve the above code snippet used to work for me perfectly. But when I deployed same code-base last week, it started breaking. I'm getting following error when trying to use as_dataframe() method

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/proto/message.py", line 555, in __getattr__
    pb_type = self._meta.fields[key].pb_type
KeyError: 'WhichOneof'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health-check.py", line 149, in check_topics_status
    result=result.select_interval(end_time=now,start_time=now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).as_dataframe()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/query.py", line 533, in as_dataframe
    return _dataframe._build_dataframe(self, label, labels)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/_dataframe.py", line 96, in _build_dataframe
    data=[_extract_value(point.value) for point in time_series.points],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/_dataframe.py", line 96, in <listcomp>
    data=[_extract_value(point.value) for point in time_series.points],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/_dataframe.py", line 49, in _extract_value
    value_type = typed_value.WhichOneof("value")

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/proto/message.py", line 560, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(str(ex))
AttributeError: 'WhichOneof'

Comment: @Steeve is it possible because of protobuf version?

Comment: FYI. pip3 freeze shows me google-cloud-monitoring==2.0.0 and protobuf==3.13.0

Comment: Let me review this @Piyush Shrivastava and I'll get back to you

Comment: Yes sure. @Steeve

Comment: @Steeve are you able to reproduce this issue at your end?

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava Updated answer to fix `WhichOneof` and removed `pandas` dependency.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your question is "no", there is no feature for PubSub that shows these counts. The way you have to do it is via log event monitoring using Stackdriver (it took me some time to find that out too).

The colloquial answer to this is do the following, step-by-step:

1. Navigate from GCloud Admin Console to: `Monitoring`

[image: navigate from gcloud admin console]

2. This opens a new window with separate Stackdriver console
3. Navigate in Stackdriver: `Dashboards` > `Create Dashboard`

[image: create new dashboard within stackdriver]

4. Click the `Add Chart` button top-right of dashboard screen

[image]

5. In the input box, type `num_undelivered_messages` and then `SAVE`

[image: auto suggested metrics to add chart]

Comment: Could the metric name be changed? I published to a topic without subscriber and do not find the metric.

Comment: look at the other answer

Answer (score 7):

Updated version based on @steeve's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185244/482899). (without `pandas` dependency)

Please note that you have to specify `end_time` instead of using default `utcnow()`.

```
import datetime
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import query

project = 'my-project'
sub_name = 'my-sub'
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
result = query.Query(
  client,
  project,
  'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages',
  end_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
  minutes=1,
  ).select_resources(subscription_id=sub_name)

for content in result:
  print(content.points[0].value.int64_value)
```

Comment: Nce work and very well done. I didn't have time to review my proposed solution. Yours work and will benefit the community

Comment: @northtree thanks for this alternative approach. Really helps.
I was still wondering why the earlier one doesn't work, since monitoring api version is same

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava I suppose it’s due to the upgrade of SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a java version

```java
package com.example.monitoring;

import static com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.create;
import static com.google.monitoring.v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.newBuilder;
import static com.google.monitoring.v3.ProjectName.of;
import static com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps.fromMillis;
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

import com.google.monitoring.v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest;
import com.google.monitoring.v3.TimeInterval;

public class ReadMessagesFromGcp {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
   
    String projectId = "put here";

    var interval = TimeInterval.newBuilder()
                               .setStartTime(fromMillis(currentTimeMillis() - (120 * 1000)))
                               .setEndTime(fromMillis(currentTimeMillis()))
                               .build();

    var request = newBuilder().setName(of(projectId).toString())
           .setFilter("metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages\"")
           .setInterval(interval)
           .setView(ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL)
           .build();

    var response = create().listTimeSeries(request);

    for (var subscriptionData : response.iterateAll()) {
        
        var subscription = subscriptionData.getResource().getLabelsMap().get("subscription_id");
        
        var numberOrMessages = subscriptionData.getPointsList().get(0).getValue().getInt64Value();
            
        if(numberOrMessages > 0) {
            System.out.println(subscription + " has " + numberOrMessages + " messages ");
        }
            
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-monitoring</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
          <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
        </dependency>
```

output

queue-1 has 36 messages

queue-2 has 4 messages

queue-3 has 3 messages

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to count all messages published to a topic using custom metrics.

In my case I am publishing messages to a Pub/Sub topic via a Cloud Composer (Airflow) Dag that runs a python script.

The python script returns logging information about the ran Dag.

```
logging.info(
f"Total events in file {counter-1}, total successfully published {counter - error_counter -1}, total errors publishing {error_counter}. Events sent to topic: {TOPIC_PATH} from filename: {source_blob_name}.",
{
"metric": "<some_name>",
"type": "completed_file",
"topic": EVENT_TOPIC,
"filename": source_blob_name,
"total_events_in_file": counter - 1,
"failed_published_messages": error_counter,
"successful_published_messages": counter - error_counter - 1,
}
```

I then have a **Distribution** custom metric which filters on **resource_type**, **resource_lable**, **jsonPayload.metric** and **jsonPayload.type**. The metric also has the **Field Name** set to jsonPayload.successful_published_messages

Custom metric filter:

```
resource.type=cloud_composer_environment AND resource.labels.environment_name={env_name} AND jsonPayload.metric=<some_name> AND jsonPayload.type=completed_file
```

That custom metric is then used in a Dashboard with the MQL setting of

```
fetch cloud_composer_environment
| metric
'logging.googleapis.com/user/my_custom_metric'
| group_by 1d, [value_pubsub_aggregate: aggregate(value.pubsub)]
| every 1d
| group_by [],
[value_pubsub_aggregate_sum: sum(value_pubsub_aggregate)]
```

Which to get to I first setup an Icon chart with **resource type:** cloud composer environment, **Metric:** my_custom metric, **Processing step:** to no preprocessing step, **Alignment function:** SUM, **period** 1, **unit** day, How do you want it grouped **group by function:** mean.

Ideally you would just select sum for the Group by function but it errors and that is why you then need to sqitch to MQL and manually enter sum instead of mean.

[image]

This will now count your published messages for up to 24 months which is the retention period set by [Google for the custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/extended-retention-times-for-custom-cloud-monitoring-metrics).