# Google pub-sub : Computing the queue size in a particular subscription

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I have been dealing with Google pub-sub (using the python API) for some time now. I wanted to collect some metrics, specifically:

(1) num_undelivered_messages
(2) num_outstanding_messages

I don't have access to a stackdriver account and I was hoping to get the metrics through the API.

I looked over this page : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/demos/ and realized that there are only three APIs available :  monitoredResourceDescriptors.list, metricDescriptors.list, and timeSeries.list

I'm not sure how any of the above can be used? Could somebody please help me out?

The relevant SO question is : [Google PubSub - Counting messages in topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475082/google-pubsub-counting-messages-in-topic)

Thanks!