# How to get total number of messages published to a topic?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

How do I get the count of number of messages published to a topic in stack driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PubSub - Counting messages in topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475082/google-pubsub-counting-messages-in-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Minu, why do you need this? There aren't any OOB Stackdriver metrics that capture this information, but you could log every time you either publish or pull a message and then use a log-based metric to aggregate...